# Why my screen shows extra string when use map() to deal with list?

Tags: python

My code is like this:

```
def f1(x):
    return x**x

L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
map(f1, L)
```

and the result shows:

```
[1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 10000000000L, 285311670611L]
```

I tried this both on my windows and Ubuntu system, it's the same result,
is there something wrong with my code or my python or something else?

Comment: Unrelated, but you could do this without defining ```f1()``` separately by doing ```map(lambda x: x**x, L)```

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the `L` appended to the numbers, it signifies that they are long integers and you shouldn't worry about it. They don't affect calculations done on them.

Comment: but if I print them out, will they still show that L on user's screen?

Comment: Nope. Try this `print '%d' % L[9]`, where `L` is your list of integers.

Comment: @Zen: No. Just print `L[10]` and have a look at the result. You don't use something like `print(L)` in your code, don't you?

Comment: I tried to type something like a=[21312321235345345345345], and print a later, it shows L in my python command line.

Comment: Because you are printing the list. If you print the individual integer, `L` doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `long` were "unified" [a few versions back](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/). Before that it was possible to overflow an `int` through math ops.

3.x has further advanced this by eliminating int altogether and only having long.

`sys.maxint` contains the maximum value a Python int can hold.